# CentOS 8 восстановить routing table

Tags: centos, маршрутизация, vpn, openvpn

Имеется: VPS сервер CentOS 8 и мои кривые руки. Хотела создать с сервера CentOS 8 VPN подключение к одному VPN (CentOS 8 = vpn клиент). Установила OpenVPN, скачала на сайте ovpn config, но после загрузки конфига командой "sudo openvpn --config str-latvia-riga.ovpn" потеряла ssh соединение к серверу (ожидала, что появится 2й tun0 интерфейс, а он, видимо, прописался как default gateway). Перезагрузила сервер, ssh поднялся. Но в таблице роутов есть записи, видимо, сделанные openvpn. Хочу их убрать и вернуть "как было", не получается. (ну и не особо разбираюсь в таблицах роутов, извините)

Собственно, вопрос: какие должны быть на сервере CentOS 8 настройки роутов "по умолчанию", если там имеется только интерфейс eth0 (интернет) и lo. Сайчас у меня там висят роуты через 169.xxx.0 и 169.xxx.100, видимо, прописанные при неудачной попытке настроить openvpn. Хочу их убрать.

```
ifconfig
eth0: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 8x.xxx.xxx.xxx  netmask 255.255.255.255  broadcast 8x.xxx.xxx.xxx
        inet6 xxxx::xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 25132  bytes 4444282 (4.2 MiB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 25511  bytes 4392781 (4.1 MiB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

route -n
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
0.0.0.0         169.xxx.100.1   0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
169.xxx.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U     1002   0        0 eth0
169.xxx.100.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0

ip a
1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN group default qlen 1000
    link/loopback 00:00:00:00:00:00 brd 00:00:00:00:00:00
    inet 127.0.0.1/8 scope host lo
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 ::1/128 scope host
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
2: eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc fq_codel state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether xx:xx:xx:xx:xx:xx brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 89.xxx.xxx.xxx/32 brd 89.xxx.xxx.xxx scope global eth0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 xxxx::xxx:xx:xxxx:xxxx/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever

ip r
default via 169.xxx.100.1 dev eth0
169.xxx.0.0/16 dev eth0 scope link metric 1002
169.xxx.100.1 dev eth0 scope link
```

Comment: добро пожаловать в 22 год 20-го века. используйте [современные средства — программу `ip`](https://unixforum.org/viewtopic.php?t=129712) // по сути вопроса: с чего вы решили, что вам требуется что-то там «восстанавливать»?

Comment: полагаю, адреса 169.xxx в роутах - остались с неудачной попытки настроить openvpn и хочу их убрать.

Comment: вероятность истинности вашего предположения скорее всего близка к нулю. но если оно всё-таки верно, то вам надо решить противоположную задачу: не **убрать** маршруты, а **не добавлять** их. и вопрос должен звучать так: «как узнать, на основании чего создаются не нужные мне маршруты?». но даже ещё прежде того, как вы зададитесь этим вопросом, вам надо определиться с тем, действительно ли они вам не нужны. // т.е. удалите их и протестируйте на предмет — всё ли необходимое вам программное обеспечение работает штатно.

Comment: ну и приложите всё-таки вывод `$ ip a; ip r`, а то из вывода древних программ ifconfig/route сложно сделать адекватные выводы.

Comment: Вполне вероятно, то моё утверждение ложное, я впервые в маршрутизации пытаюсь разобраться. 89.xxx.xxx.xxx - статический внешний ip сервера. Я полагала, что сети 169.xxx - добавляются vpn-ом, и ,если vpn я снова включу, то весь траффик отправится туда, а не в eth0.

Comment: ну вот теперь наглядно видно, что никаких «лишних» маршрутов (по крайней мере в основной таблице маршрутизации) у вас нет. ну, да, последний маршрут условно тавтологичен (дублирует дефолтный маршрут, если буквами `xxx` вы заменили везде один и тот же набор цифр), но раз вы там экспериментируете с интерфейсами/маршрутами, будет вам только на пользу. // ну и на будущее: если не хотиет «светить» реальные ip-адреса, лучше вместо вызывающей неоднозначность замены на какие-нибудь иксы замените в них одну-две цифры (в одном и том же месте в каждом адресе).

Comment: Спасибо за помощь! действительно, запустила openvpn клиента с файлом настроек, куда добавила pull-filter ignore "route-gateway" и route-nopull и туннель вроде поднялся, не убив маршрутизацию через eth0. Буду дальше ковырять.